# How to install Veewee on Windows?

Tags: powershell, vagrant, veewee

I've installed:

- [Ruby dev kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)
- [Msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)
- Added virtualbox to path environment variable
- Downloaded the repository on [github](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee)
- Went to the unzipped location with powershell
- Ran 'bundle install' in powershell

Returned: The term 'bundle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

How do I proceed?

Comment: try this: http://lucasvasconcelos.com/2013/10/how-to-install-veewee-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If you have msysgit, you should open a bash shell. Make sure that you have ruby installed and usable from the bash shell. After that first do a "gem install bundle".
Then you should be able to do "bundle install".

I got it working in Cygwin, which was an environment I'm more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked for me to the point that I was able to get veewee to run . i still have to find a way to fix the file encodings part yet (See issue 805 in the veewee github issues list )

I had vagrant 1.27 as well as VirtualBox installed before

I had to do a gem install bundle  and then had to do a bundle install

I also had to do a gem install vagrant

I had to close my command prompt and open a new one and then things worked